# High speed buffering in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stream, buffer

Ive been writing a tool which takes in a buffer at high speed from an SDR device (10  million complex samples per second (samples are short type)). But with the code I have written, I am getting small chunks missing whenever I look back at what has been written.

The way I attempted to alleviate this problem is by using two buffers of the same size and swapping between them to avoid missing any samples. The chunks go missing whenever i go through the process of swapping the buffers around and offloading the samples to a back buffer (which its size is 3 times the sample rate) and if required calls a new thread to write the new data to disk.

The SDR device itself advertises its own internal buffer size as something odd like 2016 and it gives two pointers to the real and imaginary arrays of samples. Obviously I wanted to avoid overheads of such small arrays at this sample rate so by implementing the swapping buffers with a larger size say 65536 in a hope I could hopefully avoid such problems, but to no avail.

I have pin pointed the problem to be most likely at the callback function since when I reduce the size of the swapping buffers the missing chunks become more frequent.

Am I going about this the wrong way or is there something more obvious I am missing in my solution, or have i not written something correctly?

I have avoided the standard libary as much as possible simply because it is too slow for this kind of data speed hence the need for memmove and memcpy. The only exceptions are the buffer pointer swapping and creating threads.

Swapping buffers are implemented as:

```
    IQType<short>* bufferA;
    IQType<short>* bufferB;
```

IQType is:

```
template <class T> class IQType {
public:
        T inPhaseValue;
        T quadraturePhaseValue;

        IQType() : inPhaseValue(0), quadraturePhaseValue(0){};
        IQType(T i, T q) : inPhaseValue(i), quadraturePhaseValue(q){};
};
```

SDR device callback function that unloads the SDR sample data:

```
void MiricsDataSource::newSamplesCallBack(short *xi, short *xq, unsigned int firstSampleNum, int grChanged, int rfChanged, int fsChanged, unsigned int numSamples, unsigned int reset, void *cbContext) {

    MiricsDataSource* mirCtx = static_cast<MiricsDataSource*>(cbContext);

    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i)
    {
        mirCtx->bufferA[mirCtx->bufferCount] = IQType<short>(xi[i],xq[i]);
        mirCtx->bufferCount++;
        if(mirCtx->bufferCount == mirCtx->bufferSize-1) {
            std::swap(mirCtx->bufferA,mirCtx->bufferB);
            mirCtx->owner->backBuffer->write(mirCtx->bufferB,mirCtx->bufferSize);
            mirCtx->bufferCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

BackBuffer write and related t_write functions:

```
void BackBuffer::write(const IQType<short>* buff, size_t bLength) {
    std::thread dumpThread(&BackBuffer::t_write,this,buff,bLength);
    dumpThread.detach();
}

void BackBuffer::t_write(const IQType<short>* buff, size_t bLength) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (bufferMutex);
    memmove(&backBuffer[0],(&backBuffer[0])+bLength,(sizeof(IQType<short>*)*(length-bLength)));
    memcpy(&backBuffer[length-bLength],buff,(sizeof(IQType<short>*)*(bLength)));
    if(dumpToFile) {
        IQType<short>* toWrite = new IQType<short>[bLength];
        memcpy(toWrite,buff,(sizeof(IQType<short>*)*(bLength)));
        strmDmpMgr->write(toWrite,bLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have avoided the standard library as much as possible simply because it is too slow for this kind of data speed hence the need for memmove and memcpy` I just don't buy it when I clearly see that the standard library just does memcpy/memmove when the types are trivial like in your case. If you really have not measured it, then please remove that statement.

Comment: "I have avoided the standard libary as much as possible [...] hence the need for [functions from standard library]" seems a bit contradictory.

Comment: originally i used std::rotate to move the backbuffer, but this took 5 seconds for 30 Million samples stored. memmove does this hundreds of times faster. Justy to clarify i do other things with the data in the backbuffer other than to record. The backbuffer is also used to observe the last 3 seconds of the recorded data. Its treated similarly to a queue but with the option to look at any position and any length up to the size of the backbuffer

Comment: @Gelion `rotate` is not at all the standard replacement for `memove`!  It does a lot more work than what you need.

Comment: So why exactly do you need two buffers and swapping shenanigans instead of just implementing a large enough ring buffer? Shouldn't need any locking and multiple dynamic threads either, we're talking about a mere 20MB/s here, just go for a single reader and writer thread and you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The biggest cost is spawning a thread in `BackBuffer::write`. Don't do this, just run a single persistent background thread and send it a message.
2. There's a risk in your current setup of corrupting output buffers (filling the second buffer before your thread finishes with the first buffer allows you to start overwriting the first buffer again). You can handle an arbitrary number of buffers by just using a queue of full buffers and a queue of empty buffers to cycle them between your threads.

   Make the background thread responsible for creating new buffers if you fall below some minimal level of free ones to keep dynamic allocation out of the critical loop.
3. As Voo says, just reading directly into your big buffer (and avoiding the intermediate `memcpy` etc.) is simpler still. It does have less elasticity than the list-of-buffers approach, but it's not obvious you need the flexibility here.

There are some smaller optimisations (eg. don't increment the buffer count through an indirection every iteration, just store the correct value once), but that thread is the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

One possible source is that you create a new thread for each "data dump". Depending on the buffer sizes you can create thousands of threads per second which can lead to severe performance degradation, not only of your program but for the whole computer. Creating a single thread is an expensive operation, not to mention the operating has to cycle between all your threads *plus* all the other threads on the system.

Instead I suggest a different design, where you have a pool of already running threads (search for `c++ thread pools`) that you ask do dump a buffer. Then you could have a circular ring of buffers, one for each thread plus one where you currently writing.

Comment: I just checked how many threads it uses and it stays around 15 (according to windows). Is there a more accurate way of seeing how many are spawned?